# state variables in Perl Mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

In a [Mojolicous](https://docs.mojolicious.org/) full app, I have a model helper which returns a hash. I would like to update the contents of this hash (from a downloaded CSV) on a regular basis.

**My question**: How can I make `users` a state variable (and/or use [`Mojo::Base has`](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Base#has)?) so I don't read from the file upon every call? That is, during the call to `update`, `delete` the `users` hash and re-create it, if download is successful?

I present a Lite example just to demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve:

- [`GET /update`](http://localhost:3000/update) - downloads an updated CSV, and stores it as `${epoch}.json` (I need this to update the hash if download is successful)
- [`GET /`](http://localhost:3000/) - lists users, by reading the newest `${epoch}.json` file and returning the desired hash. (This should just return the hash, and not read the file upon every call.)

```perl
use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;

helper users => sub($self) {
    my $users;
    my $newest;
    foreach my $filename (sort {$b cmp $a} glob("1*.csv")) {
        $newest = $filename;
        last;
    }
    open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $newest or die $!;
    while (<$fh>) {
        next if $. == 1; # ignore CSV header
        my ($name,$email,$phone) = split(',');
        $users->{$email} = $name;
    }
    close($fh);
    $users;
};

helper update => sub ($self) {
    my $tx = $self->ua->get( 'https://test-backend.lambdatest.com/api/dev-tools/csv-generator' );
    my $res = eval { $tx->result };
    return $@ if $@;
    my $epoch = Mojo::Date->new()->epoch;
    Mojo::File->new( "${epoch}.csv" )->spurt( $res->text );
    return 'ok';
};

get '/' => sub ($self) {
    my @names = sort values %{ $self->users };
    $self->render(json => {emails=>[@names]} );
    
};

get '/update' => sub ($self) {
    $self->render(text => $self->update );
};

app->start;
```

In my full app, my code looks like:

```perl
$self->helper(users => sub {state $data = MyApp::Model::Users->new(app => $self)});
```

Then in `Users.pm`:

```perl
package MyApp::Model::Users;
use Mojo::Base -base, -signatures;
use Text::CSV_XS;

has 'app';
has 'users' => sub($self) {
  my $users;
    open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $self->app->config->{'filename'} or die $!;
    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ diag_verbose=>1, auto_diag=>1, binary=>1, sep_char=>";" });
    $csv->getline($fh); # Ignore Header
    while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {        
        $users->{ $row->[0] } = $row->[1];
    }
    close($fh);
    $users;
};
```

My problem with this code is that I don't know how to update `users` after the initial setup.

##### EDIT

I figured out how to do it in a full-app, but I don't know how to access the `$self->users`. In a full-app, I would do: `$self->helper(users => sub {state $data = MyApp::Model::Users->new(app => $self)});`

```perl
use Mojolicious::Lite -base, -signatures;

has 'users' => sub($self) {
    my $users = {};
    my $newest;
    foreach my $filename (sort {$b cmp $a} glob("1*.csv")) {
        $newest = $filename;
        last;
    }
    $self->updateUsers($newest, $users);
    $users;
};

helper updateUsers => sub($self, $filename, $users=undef) {
    say STDERR "### updateUsers($filename)";
    $users //= $self->users;
    delete @$users{keys %$users}; # delete existing hash
    open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $filename or die $!;
    while (<$fh>) {
        next if $. == 1; # ignore CSV header
        my ($name,$email,$phone) = split(',');
        $users->{$email} = $name;
    }
    close($fh);
    $users;
};

helper update => sub ($self) {
    my $tx = $self->ua->get( 'https://test-backend.lambdatest.com/api/dev-tools/csv-generator' );
    my $res = eval { $tx->result };
    return $@ if $@;
    my $epoch = Mojo::Date->new()->epoch;
    my $file = Mojo::File->new( "${epoch}.csv" )->spurt( $res->text );
    $self->update( $file->to_string );    
    return 'ok';
};

get '/' => sub ($self) {
    my @names = sort values %{ $self->users };
    $self->render(json => {emails=>[@names]} );
    
};

get '/update' => sub ($self) {
    $self->render(text => $self->update );
};

app->start;
```

Comment: The motive behind this question is to update `users` on a scheduled basis. I have a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76787883/crontab-for-perl-mojolicous) posted.

Comment: I think that depends a little bit on your deployment. If you have multiple workers (so for example a pre-fork deployment) in-memory storage applies to each individual worker process. Even if  you load the data at start-up, then every new worker that's being forked will get the initial state, and make changes to it individually for itself. If you want them to share data, you will have to look at other data storages. The filesystem is one such storage. A MMap might work, or something like Redis or another key/value store.

Comment: That said, there is a `state` keyword in Perl that you can enable. It gives you lexically scoped variables that maintain their value with every call. I believe the Mojo docs show examples of this within `helper`s.

Comment: Thank you @simbabque. I am using state in my full-app: `$self->helper(users => sub {state $data = MyApp::Model::Users->new(app => $self)});`. My problem is I don't know how to update it once initialized.

Comment: `state` variables are not constants. You can just assign a new value. Only the initialisation bit on the line with the `state` declaration is run once, but subsequent `$data = 'foo'` will run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a better way to do your task, but let's talk about the particular language issue first.

But, one general approach is to set up a persistent (`state`) variable. When you first enter the subroutine, check that value of that variable. If it has a value, return it. If not, figure out its value and assign it:

```
sub get_data {
    state $data;
    return $data if defined $data;

    $data = ...
    }
```

But I think your architectural problem is something different. Your web app doesn't need to be the part responsible for updating the data. Do that out-of-band. Something checks the source periodically, downloads new data as appropriate, and then updates the data store. Your web app only looks at the data store.

```
sub get_data {
    state $data;
    state $serial;

    my $lastest_serial = ...; # however you want to tag the data
    undef $data unless $latest_serial eq $serial; # invalidate somehow
    return $data if defined $data;

    $serial = $latest_serial;
    $data = ...
    }
```

But, sometimes you want to invalidate that data. You might share that variable with another subroutine that can do the trick:

```
{
my $data;

sub get_data { ... }

sub invalidate_data { undef $data }
}
```

}

We cover this sort of persistent, private variable sharing in [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com). There are many ways you can get to the same goal.

It would be better if your web app never thought about this, though. Your controller asks the model for the data it needs and it gets it. The controller doesn't tell the model when to update. Something external, such as cron updates that rather than waiting for something to hit a URL. Maybe that's SQLite or some heavier database. There are a variety of ways to handle this.